# Generate a list of all background jobs on a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have tried `ActiveJob::Base.descendants` `ApplicationJob.descendants` both of which return `[]`. Any other quick trick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `Rails.application.eager_load!` before `ApplicationJob.descendants`. It should do the trick